# Keeping a subprocess alive between Django views

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have an interactive console application that keeps track of 3D items and their positions. I have set up a Django server so that a user can remotely interact with this application via ajax calls.

I currently create a subprocess for my console application to run. Then, I would like to hold onto this object and pass it to the other views according to what the user does. Is there a way to do this?

The object I create with subprocess.Popen is not serializable. Therefore, my last attempt was to save pipe names into request.session, and try to use them on the other views. However, I am getting a "bad file descriptor" error, and I assume this is because the child process is terminated once it goes out of scope in the first view. Is there a way to keep the subprocess alive and maintain a handle to it between Django views?

Maybe subprocess is not the correct way to go about this... Should I try to make a daemon? Would that be helpful? I'm not sure it is the right solution though.

My last attempt was trying to make the Popen object global. However, in the new view I only received "Bad pipe" errors when attempting to use its pipes. I also tried to use the python cache but it does not seem to be possible to store Popen objects in there.

Comment: You could try using [threading.local](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local)

Comment: The two views appear to run under different threads, sadly.

Comment: Why don't you save the complete Popen object in request.session? Alas, this won't scale well, but maybe it doesn't need to.

Comment: I cannot save it because it needs to be serializable to be saved into request.session.